# Haskell - Illegal literal in type error in a function definition

Tags: haskell, types, literals, ghci

I have the following function:

```
replace :: a -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
replace elem 0 x:xs = elem : xs
replace elem i x:xs = x ++ replace elem (i - 1) xs
```

And GHCi tells me that I have an illegal literal in type error, specifically on the literal 0 in the first definition.  Now, I'm aware that if I'm trying to replace an arbitrary item in a list that I should not be using the list data structure. That is fine, as I am planning on refactoring my program as soon as I can get what I want to work.

As far as the compiler complaint, I'm not really sure why Haskell believes I'm trying to define a type here.  Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Write `(x:xs)` instead of `x:xs` in the pattern and `x :` instead of `x ++`. I'm not sure why it complains about type literals - when I compile it, I get "parse error in pattern: replace" which is what I would expect.

Comment: @user2407038 your comment is an answer, so should really have been posted as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @user2407038 mentioned there are two direct problems with your code - you mising parens and you use `(++)` instead of `(:)` - you can solve this like this:

```
replace :: a -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
replace elem 0 (x:xs) = elem : xs
replace elem i (x:xs) = x : replace elem (i - 1) xs
```

but doing so will still leave you with only a partial definition as you do not match empty lists of `a` s (and GHC will tell you so with a warning) - to solve this just add the missing case:

```
replace :: a -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
replace _    _ []     = []
replace elem 0 (x:xs) = elem : xs
replace elem i (x:xs) = x : replace elem (i - 1) xs
```

finally you can remove some unused bindings (variables) and rename `elem` (is already definied in the prelude) to make GHC even more happy (-Wall):

```
replace :: a -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
replace _  _ []     = []
replace el 0 (_:xs) = el : xs
replace el i (x:xs) = x : replace el (i - 1) xs
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing one empty space of indentation.  I believe the compiler thought this segment of code was part of the previous (unrelated) expression.  Also, I took the advice of a commenter and replaced `x ++` with `x :`

Comment: Yes, top level definitions are considered to be in a `where` block (started by the (optional) `module` declaration) and need to be indented the same amount.